# Changing the language of MSI installer (WIX)

Tags: visual-studio, localization, wix, windows-installer

I have written an installer for my program, using WIX for Visual Studio 2012.

I want to make it **Spanish-only**.

I though that I will achieve it by (1034 is Spanish code, according to [wix tutorial](http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial/user-interface/do-you-speak-english)):

```
<Product Id="..." Name="..." Language="1034" Version="1.1.0.0" 
Manufacturer="..." UpgradeCode="...">

<Package InstallerVersion="301" Compressed="yes"  Languages="1034" />
```

But my installer is still in English. I am using Windows in Polish version, VS in English (if it's imporntant).

I also use **WixUI_Advanced**.

**What else I have to add to make that MSI Spanish?**

The (almost) full code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">

 <Product Id="..." Name="..." Language="1034" Version="1.1.0.0" 
Manufacturer="..." UpgradeCode="...">

<Package InstallerVersion="301" Compressed="yes"  Languages="1034" />

<Icon Id="icon.ico" SourceFile="../../icon.ico"/>
<Property Id="ARPPRODUCTICON" Value="icon.ico" />

<Media Id="1" Cabinet="media1.cab" EmbedCab="yes" />


<!--Directory structure-->
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">...</Directory>

<DirectoryRef Id="...">...</DirectoryRef>

<UIRef Id="WixUI_Advanced"  />
  <WixVariable Id="WixUILicenseRtf" Value="../../license-esp.rtf" />
<Property Id="ApplicationFolderName" Value="FxCleaner" />
<Property Id="WixAppFolder" Value="WixPerMachineFolder" />
<WixVariable Id="WixUIBannerBmp" Value="../../icon.bmp" />

<!--Features-->
<Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="FxCleaner Main" Level="1">...</Feature>
</Product>
</Wix>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you forget to compile with

```
-cultures:es-ES
```

Comment: Indeed, I forgot it. I'm compiling my Wix script in VS ("build"), not a command line itself, so if somebody cannot find that option: I added "es-ES" to <My Project> (in Solution Explorer) -> Properties -> Build -> Cultures (than "Save"). THANK YOU Magog :)